# Using promises to observe a cursor and stop cursor

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise, ecmascript-2016

I can't quite find a good way to do this, but here is my basic method. Its goal is to observe the state of an object until it finds a message that matches a regex.

```
Cylon.waitForMessage(regex) {
  check(regex, RegExp);

  const observer = this.connections.find({
    name: 'messages'
  }).observe({
    changed: function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.lastMessage) // this is the last message to scan.
    }
  });
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // need to find the last message here and check if it matches regex
  }).then(() => observer.stop());

  return Promise.await(promise);
}
```

What is the appropriate way to do this? How can you stop a listener or observer after a promise is completed?

Comment: Why not just stop the observer from inside the `changed` function? Test the message on that function and if it passes just stop the observer.

Comment: Because I need it to wait for the message before continuing to the next step, otherwise it will try to send too many commands at once.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the logic inside the `promise` function:

```
const observer = this.connections.find({
    name: 'messages'
});

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    observer.observe({
        changed: function(doc){
            if(regex.test(doc.lastMessage)){
               resolve(doc.lastMessage);
               observer.stop();
            }
        });
    });
  }).then((message) => doSomethingWithResolvedMessage());
```